# Upgraded to Intellij 2018.1 and now I'm getting an error for public static final String constants that are referenced in SQL code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2018

All my classes that have public static final String NAME = "value" that are used in SQL queries are now getting a compiler error " or DELIMITER expected, got 'lastname'".

[image]

You can also find the code below in case it helps replicate it.

```
public class PeopleSQL
{
    public static final String ID_COL = "id";
    public static final String FIRSTNAME_COL = "firstname";
    public static final String LASTNAME_COL = "lastname";

    public static void getListOfPeople(Connection connection) throws RanaSQLException
    {
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        ResultSet result = null;

        try
        {
            statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT " + ID_COL + ", " + LASTNAME_COL + " FROM people");
            result = statement.executeQuery();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try
            {
                result.close();
                statement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}


class People
{

}
```

And yes I've filed a bug report.

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with the file encoding, so it breaks IDEA's code parser

Comment: I did nothing other than just upgrade the IDE

Comment: Also if I delete it and manually re-type it in the error stays

Comment: It seems to only affect constants that end with _COL

Comment: report a bug...

Comment: Or code that's related to databases...

Comment: For the reference, the filed issue is [IDEA-188988](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-188988)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug with the new Intellij 2018.1 Edition and a bug report has been issued: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-188988

Below is a screenshot of the temporary workaround. You basically need to disable a setting.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - had the same issue and your workaround got me over the hurdle.